# How do I run some commands when linux boots for the first time

Tags: linux, boot

I want to run some system initialization commands if and only if the system is booting for the first time.  Specifically, I want to generate identity keys and submit a CSR for signing.  I want to do this only once so the identity cert will remain valid through reboots. I don't want to simply check the filesystem to see if the cert has already been created because if an attacker could write their own cert and keys to the boot image file(s) they could install their own identity.

My question is, How do I determine if Linux is booting for the first time?

Thanks,

Comment: It depends on the distribution used.

Comment: The concept is generally: configure the system with a service/script that runs on every boot and have that check for a marker that is set after it completes the first full run. If that is not found, run the rest of the script,  otherwise exit gracefully. Or the service/script disables/removes itself after completion . - [cloudinit](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is a popular tool to  initialize a system on (first) boot.

Comment: If an attacker can write to your filesystem system then he can reset any markers of the first boot.